# Prove the all cheaters will be killed

Tags: number-theory, induction

In a city there is a law against infidelity. It is postulated that there are women who have cheated on their husbands. Also, if a woman cheated on her husband, all the people in the city except her husband know this fact. Now husbands should just think logically without asking others or investigating on their own. Everyone understands the law that if a husband's wife cheated on him, then he must kill her by the next morning. Prove that eventually, after several days, all the wives who cheated will be killed.

My try : I proved it intuitive for two pairs of people but I can't change it to algebraic forms and prove it using induction.

Comment: Please, show us your effort.

Comment: I remember a problem of sort. Just without the medieval setting.

Comment: O..K.., that's horrible. Can you recast this problem in slightly less violent terms? And preferably with clearer verb tenses?

Comment: This is usually phrased as the blue-eyed islanders problem.

Comment: By the way, not at all mathematical but entertaining. https://slatestarcodex.com/2015/10/15/it-was-you-who-made-my-blue-eyes-blue/

Comment: google "blue forehead problem" for an isomorphic, less violent version

Comment: @Joffan I just translated it from the other language . If it's bad , I'm really sorry .

Comment: @Arnaldo I added it.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Can you provide that ?

Comment: I think they should all go out and get drunk, and lose count of which day they're on. Far safer.

Comment: @S.H.W It was the one Patrick Stevens mentioned.

Comment: @Joffan Yes , it's right without any doubt :) I thought it's interesting question therefore put it on this website.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I saw that but it seems different from this question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: BTW: I think it may be important that everyone knows that everyone knows that there exists an unfaithful wife, and that everyone knows that everyone knows that everyone knows that there exists an unfaithful wife etc. etc. When I tell people the blue forehead problem I usually take care of this by saying that everyone is told simultaneously that there exists an unfaithful wife, and that everyone is aware that everyone else is a perfect reasoner.

Comment: This is a pure gem of MSE.

Comment: The problem is pefectly valid, and the context is no more stupid than Kirkman's Schoolgirls problem. Plus, the outrageous violence is hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that the law should be

> if husband finds out, that his wife cheated on him, then he must kill her by the next morning

Then the reasoning is easy:

- if there is one cheating wife, then her husband sees, that every other wifes are faithful, so his wife have to the one cheating. He kills her in first night.
- if there are $n>1$ cheating wifes, the cheated husbands see $n-1$ cheating wifes and don't have to think, that their wife is cheating on them. Also they think, that the cheating wives will be killed in $(n-1)$th night. But after that night nobody was killed (because cheated husbands thought, that only the other $n-1$ were cheated), so there have to be $n$th cheating wife. So in the $n$th night all $n$ wives are killed.

There is also more brutal way to kill all cheating wifes - burn all the witches! ;)

**Edit**

Interesting thing is that if there were no cheating wives (what is 'against the law', that there should be at least one), all innocent women would be killed by their husbands in the first night. So one wife have to 'sacrifice' herself and cheat on her husband to save all the other women.

Comment: How they know there are $n$ numbers of cheating wives ?

Comment: @S.H.W Because if there were $n-1$ cheating wives, they would all be killed in $(n-1)$th night.